# Sieve of Eratosthenes, Prime Numbers C

Tags: c, math, numbers, primes

I'm writing a program to find the primes number until 1000, using the Sieve of Eratosthenes...But it doesn't work...Here is my entire code, but the "calculation" to find the primes number are inside the function "markPrimes"(I'm confident saying that the rest of the code is ok, so I'm pretty sure that the problem is in this function...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct primal
{
    int number; /* a number */
    char mark;  /* flag marking the number as active (1) or inactive (0) */
} primal;


void initialize(primal *s,int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        s[i].number=i+1;
        s[i].mark=1; //1=prime number 
    }
}

void markPrimes(primal *s,int size)
{
    /* add this function - it should mark all of the numbers in the passed primal array that are not prime numbers as inactive */
    //Brute Sieve of Eratosthenes Approach (0=not prime number)

    s[0].mark=0; //s[0].number=1 as on the function "initialize" I start from 1 not from 0
    int i,j;
    for (unsigned i = 2; i*i <size; i++)
    {
        if (s[i].mark == 1)
            for (unsigned j = i<<1;j<size;j+=i)
                s[j].mark = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,prime_numbers[200];
    primal source_numbers[1000]; /* an array of source values */

    for(i=0;i<200;i++) prime_numbers[i]=0; /* initialize the prime numbers array to 0 */

    initialize(source_numbers,1000); /* initialize the source numbers array to hold the numbers 1-1000 */

    markPrimes(source_numbers,1000); /* identify the prime numbers in the source numbers array */

    /* copy the primes from the source numbers to the prime numbers array */
    for(i=0,j=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if(source_numbers[i].mark==1) /* if the current source number is a prime */
        {
            prime_numbers[j]=source_numbers[i].number; /* copy the number */
            j++; /* increment the target index */
        }
    }

    /* print the prime numbers */
    for(i=0,j=0;prime_numbers[i]!=0;i++,j++)
    {
        printf("%3d ",prime_numbers[i]);
        if(j==9) /* periodically print a newline and then reset j */
        {
            printf("\n");
            j=-1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Just what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What exactly is your question? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could simplify things by not using the structure but use a simple array of `char` or `bool`.  The primality of N is found by checking element N of the array.  You can keep 0 and 1 in the array because it's harder to remove them and the wasted space is negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is known to allow for the progammer to punctuate their foot (don't worry, everyone of us has such a scar), and that's what happened here.

In your inner loop, you start at *1* instead of *0*, so you need to take the actual number  minus one as the index and add that number instead of the index:

```
void markPrimes(primal *s,int size)
{
    //Brute Sieve of Eratosthenes Approach (0=not prime number)

    int i,j;
    // 1 (one) is not prime per definition
    s[0].mark = 0;
    for (i = 1; i*i <size; i++)
    {;
        if (s[i].mark == 1) {
            // you start at 1 instead of 0, so you need to take the actual number
            // minus one as the index and add that number instead of the index.
            for ( j = 2 * s[i].number  - 1;j < size; j += s[i].number){
                s[j].mark = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it totally works now ^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem in in your starting point for Sieve of Eratosthenes.

> for (unsigned i = 1; i*i

This loop should start from 2 instead of 1. What you are basically doing is marking all your numbers as non-prime initially.

Instead, mark 0 and 1 manually as non-prime, by doing s[0].mark=0; s[1].mark=1. Then start loop from i=2

Comment: I changed as you said starting the for loop from 2 and not from 1...Plus I initialized s[0].mark=0(I don't have the number 0 as I start to fill the array from the number 1 not from 0, and I inizitalied 1 .mark=0[1 is not a prime number so I don't get why I should initialize it at 1])